# Web3.py web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted on getAmountOutMin and swap functions

Tags: python, web3py

Essentially I am trying to use a token swap function for web3.py and upon calling the function, it is giving me a ContractLogic Error: execution reverted which occurs on both getAmountOutMin as well as the swap function. I have looked thoroughly through the docs and other posts and I am unsure as to why this code is reproducing this error. I would appreciate it if someone could find a solution to this.

Here is the code used:

```
uniswap_factory_abi = json.loads('''[
        {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "_tokenIn",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "_tokenOut",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "_amountIn",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "_amountOutMin",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "_to",
                    "type": "address"
                }
            ],
            "name": "swap",
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        },
                {
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "_tokenIn",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "_tokenOut",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "_amountIn",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "getAmountOutMin",
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
            }]''')

actual_min = float(min)
amountout = contract.functions.getAmountOutMin("0xd0A1E359811322d97991E03f863a0C30C2cF029C", "0xF6fF8efc1e11A17E410F248475ffE870E8FC6ebD", int(actual_min * 1e18))


txn = {
    'from': account,
    'gas': 650000,
    'gasPrice': web3.eth.gasPrice,
    'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account)
}


amountoutmin = amountout.call(txn)

token_swap = contract.functions.swap("0xd0A1E359811322d97991E03f863a0C30C2cF029C", "0xF6fF8efc1e11A17E410F248475ffE870E8FC6ebD", int(actual_min * 1e18), amountoutmin, account)

token_swap.call(txn)
```

edit:

After using solcx to compile the solidity code, it has solved my issue

edit2:

Apparently using solcx to compile the solidity code did not solve the issue, however I have now found out that the solidity code that I have been using for this has been faulty, which is the source of my problems

Answer (score 0):

I would try to check first if your contract deployed successfully and then see if the functions you use work fine too. Not sure what you used to deploy it, but in Remix for example you can use the web interface to test your functions and there's a nice dubug feature as well. Type in the values there, check the output and if it works then move to the code part. My guess is that your txn might be missing some parameters like chainId, value, etc. Do you sign the transaction too?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29864784)